# Can't enter Windows after "Erase Ubuntu and reinstall it"

Tags: boot, grub2, windows, partitioning

I was running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a dual-boot with the preinstalled Windows 8.1 that came with my laptop.

I was messing around with the launcher interface (You know the cube thing and all that graphical stuff) and I wanted to go back, so I reinstalled Ubuntu with a live USB.

There was an option that said **Erase Ubuntu and reinstall it** So I obviously picked that one.

Everything installed ok, and I am currently running Ubuntu. But the dual-boot screen at start wasn't showing ok... (There was something like a black canvas on it) So I wasn't able to select any option from that screen, and was booting directly to Ubuntu.

After running boot repair I was able to see the GRUB menu with boot options, but there was no Windows option.

Another thing I noticed is that the hard drive doesn't have the 40 GB space that I made on Windows for the Ubuntu partition. Instead, it has almost the whole drive (1 TB) and I am really scared that the process has deleted all my Windows and my stuff.

[Here is the URL](http://paste2.org/nxWgZ7y4) that boot repair gave to me when finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using terminal:

```
sudo lshw |less
```

Then, try to check the storage info. It will list all partitions available in your computer.

Looking at the report, I'm sorry to tell you that your Windows had been wiped out. If you wish to use Windows, you need to reinstall it.

Comment: Does the recovery partition still there? Because When I enter the recovery from the assist button of my computer (Vaio Fit 14) and hit the recovery option it boots again on grub and can't enter to the windows recovery partition.

Comment: Sadly, no. I sisn't see any other partition except EFI boot manager, Linux, and swap partition only.

Answer (score 0):

Check first if your windows partitions are there.

Maybe change some settings in the BIOS?

Or use boot-repair: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair